# Deploy only one azure function to Function Apps (has many functions)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function app in azure which has many functions. And, I have a solution which has 6-7 projects (azure function), now, I would like to deploy only one function which has some changes, to azure portal. While deploying only one modified function to azure portal, other functions are getting deleted. Please suggest some way to deploy only one function to portal instead of all the functions.

**Example:**

**Function app in portal:** 
*Function1 Function2 Function3 Function4, Function5, Function6, Function7*

**Visual studio solution**

**Project 1:** *Function1, Function2*

**Project 2**: *Function3*

**Project 3**: *Function4, Function5*

**Project 4**: *Function6*

**Project 5**: *Function7*

There is change in *Function3*, when I deploy *Function3*, existing *Function1, Function2, Function4, Function5, Function6, Function7* are getting deleted.

Kindly suggest some solution to deploy only *Function3* without deleting *Function1 & Function2 & Function4, Function5, Function6, Function7*

Thanks

Comment: Why not you accept the answer when it helps you solve the problem? Why you ignore other's help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using visual studio, when you deploy function, there is a setting to configure this.

There is a setting called `Delete Existing Files`, in Profile Settings called Removed additional files at destination.
The default value is true, uncheck this setting it won't delete your function in your app.

[image]

[image]

**Update**:If you use vs2017, you could edit with `Manage Profile Settings`, then you will be able to edit this value.

[image]

**Update**: when you publish it choose Create Profile, then you could edit the pubxml file. The parameter `SkipExtraFilesOnServer` is used to control the same setting, if you don't want to delete the azure function set it to true.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you George for your help!!!!
At first, I have tried to set "Delete existing files" to false. But, it is not editable. I am using Visual Studio 2017. 
Just to be more clear, I am publishing using ".PublishSettings" file.  
Even I have tried to google to get some solution. But, I did not find any solution. Any help in this regard is very thankful from my side.

Comment: @Jayanth Kulkarni ,I have update the answer. If this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot George!!!!!! It has worked out, but, the moment we select ".PublishSettings" file, publish gets started. At first time it value would be set to True for "Delete existing files". Before deploying for second time we can change value. This is repetation of deployment with value as true for first time and false as second time. We have to set "Delete existing files" value to false prior to selecting ".PublishSettings". If you have any solution, please help. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Jayanth Kulkarni, check my new update now. Suppose this could help you.

Comment: But in my case, I am deploying by using Import Profile, I mean deploying using  ".PublishSettings" file. I have tried editing the file by adding SkipExtraFilesOnServer . But, it did't work.

Comment: I test with `.PublishSettings `file, after importing the file I could also edit the  `pubxml file`, and what do you mean it didn't work.

Comment: Assuming SkipExtraFilesOnServer  could work with ".PublishSettings", I have given a try. In my case i am deploying using import profile option. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Jayanth Kulkarni, if this could help you, please accept it [as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Notice that this is not recommended by Microsoft. Function Apps are the unit of deployment, and any other method is "not supported" - this works due to how dotnet pack functions, but if something goes wrong, you are on your own: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Deploying-Function-Apps-vs-individual-Functions